# Is there a rtsp delivery server?

Tags: rtsp

I want to make a `rtsp` delivery server.

```
rtsp publisher --> [rtsp delivery server] --> rtsp player
```

I know that the wowza server can achieve.
But I want to make it like a `nginx` without wowza.

If you have an information, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your subject mentions RTSP but contents only RTMP.

- For RTSP to RTMP, Wowza SE is required to input RTSP and re-stream as RTMP or directly HTML5 HLS to web pages.
  https://www.wowza.com/pricing/streaming-engine

You can license Wowza SE and install on own dedicated server or get a turnkey plan for lower costs and hassle from $50/month:
https://webrtchost.com

- For RTMP to RTMP, an option is Red5, free open source RTMP server, if you have a VPS or dedicated server.

If you don't have your own dedicated server to install, you can get a turnkey RTMP service. There are providers from as low as $9/month: 
https://hostrtmp.com